# how to do sumproduct in R by dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I just want to achieve a thing on R. Here is the explanation,

I have data sets which contains same value, please find the below data sets,

```
A           B
1122513454  0
1122513460  0
1600041729  0
2100002632  147905
2840007103  0
2840064133  138142
3190300079  138040
3190301011  138120
3680024411  0
4000000263  4000000263
4100002263  4100002268
4880004352  138159
4880015611  138159
4900007044  0
7084781116  142967
7124925306  0
7225002523  7225001325
23012600000 0
80880593057 0
98880000045 0
```

I have two columns (A & B). In the b column, I have the same value (138159,138159). It appears two times.

I just want to make a calculation, where it will get the same value it will count as 1. That means, I am getting two 138159, but that will be treated as 1. and finally it will count the whole b column value except 0. That means, 0 is here 10 times and the other value is also 10 times, but 138519 appears 2 times, so it will be counted as 1, so other values are 9 times and finally it will give me only other value's count i.e 9.

So my expected output will be `9`

I have already done this in excel. But, want to achieve the same in R. Is there any way to do it in R by `dplyr` package?

I have written following formula in excel,

```
=+SUMPRODUCT((I2:I14<>0)/COUNTIFS(I2:I14,I2:I14))
```

how can I count only other value's record without 0?

Can you guys help me with that?

any suggestion is really appreciable.

Edit 1: I have done this by following way,

```
abc <- hardy[hardy$couponid !=0,]
```

```
undertaker <- abc %>%
              group_by(TYC) %>%
              summarise(count_couponid= n_distinct(couponid))
```

any smart way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: `df %>% filter(B != 0) %>% summarise(n = n_distinct(B))`?

Comment: Thanks, It works..

Comment: @Sayananalytics please use "grammarly" or any other spell checker.